# Что использовать для клиент-серверного приложения?

Tags: сокет, websocket, grpc

Хочу сделать вебсайт для контроля пк. На компьютере запускаеться приложение клиент и пользователь к нему может удалённо подключиться через вебсайт и выполнять запросы (прислать скриншот, нажать клавишу и т.д.) Как правильно организовать подключение? Если через вебсокеты, то как подключаться к вебсайту? Сразу при запуске программы на пк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, использовать вебсокеты придется.
Саму программу можно добавить, в принципе, в автозапуск, чтобы доступ был всегда - пусть слушает порт сайта, а как пользователь подключится к сайту для управления ПК, то сайт должен кинуть запрос на подключение к ПК (это должно происходить автоматом). А уже остальное при помощи запросов делать.
Стек использования, в принципе, совершенно любой.